# can i create collection of collections in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I want to store emails in mongodb, the email is in json format
each email has an id and several emails can have the same id so i want to group the emails according to the id

expectation in mongodb

Emails(collection):
id1(collection):email1,email2,email3,
id2(collection):email1,email2,email3,
id3(collection):email1,email2,email3,
id4(collection):email1,email2,email3

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of emails? MongoDB supports JSON objects so it's trivial to do that

Answer (score 0):

An example shema

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const models = new Schema({
   email: {
     type: String,
     default: false,
     required: true
   }
});
module.exports = model('<collectionname>', models);
```